# Check array value inside for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have to check **second   value in array** if is equal to **zero**. It's working on my first example, where is user input not looped. But is not working on second example, where user input is looped.

## First example

```
int[] array = new int[4];

array[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
array[1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

> ```
> //This statement Works here
> ```

```
if (array[1] == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alert!");
}
array[2] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
array[3] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

---

## Second example

```
int[] array = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i = i + 1)
{ 
    //Input
    array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

> ```
> //This statement is not working
> ```

```
if (array[1] == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Alert!");
}
```

Comment: Can you print `array[1]` in the second case and see what's in it?

Comment: It seems like this is homework, isn't it?

Comment: It works perfect (after i add the miss } ), What the problem?

Comment: Array[1] is second value. In my case is "2".

Comment: I have missing } in my code, I just skipped it when I was copying this code. And its still not working.

Comment: If Array[1] = 2 nothing should be happen, why do you think that its mistake?

Comment: What's your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I just had to write this if statement *outside* the loop. Now it Works

```
int[] array = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i = i + 1)
{ 
    //Input
    array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

if (array[1] == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Alert!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe want to do that:

```
int[] array = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i = i + 1)
{ 
    //Input
    array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (array[i] == 0) // use i instead of 1
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alert!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you use [i], then is meant for all array fields, but I strictly needed only for specific value.

Answer (score 0):

to be sure to acuire valid values rom user you could use `int.TryParse()` instead of `int.Parse()`

```
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i = i + 1)
        {
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out array[i]))
                Console.WriteLine("Input an integer value!");                    
        }

        if (array[1] == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alert!");
        }
```